# How does the number of braces affect uniform initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, uniform-initialization, list-initialization

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A() {}
  A(const A&) {}
};

struct B {
  B(const A&) {}
};

void f(const A&) { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
void f(const B&) { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }

int main() {
  A a;
  f(   {a}   ); // A
  f(  {{a}}  ); // ambiguous
  f( {{{a}}} ); // B
  f({{{{a}}}}); // no matching function
}
```

Why does each call fabricate the corresponding output? How does the number of braces affect uniform initialization? And how does brace elision affect all this?

Comment: Completely attracted. But I think you' d better post your complier message. :)

Comment: @Constructor the comments give the error messages when compiling with (at least) g++, else what is written during the execution

Comment: @bruno Yes, I complied it with clang, and the results are same.

Comment: may want to add the tag `language-lawyer`

Comment: Nit: semicolons after member function definitions are pointless and let the uninitiated imagine things like all closing braces should get one.

Comment: @DavisHerring Allow meaningless semicolons in the syntax was a design error IMHO

Comment: @curiousguy Well, we're lucky we have them since if not we wouldn't be able to write `[[fallthrough]];`. :)

Comment: @DavisHerring Of course, thanks! I don’t know what got into me. :)

Comment: @Rakete1111: There are more uses for null *statements* than null *declarations* (that are not also statements).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) is fun like this.

1. `{a}` has *exact match* rank for initializing (a temporary for) the `const A&` parameter, which outcompetes the user-defined conversion `B(const A&)` as a realization of `{a}`.  This rule was **added in C++14** to resolve ambiguities in list-initialization (along with adjustments for aggregates).

   Note that the notional temporary is **never created**: after overload resolution picks `f(const A&)`, the reference is simply [initialized to refer to `a`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.9), and this interpretation [can apply](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jb0EImHMyY6WXbHx) even for non-copyable types.
2. It would be permissible to initialize a `const A&` parameter (as above) to the constructor for *either* `A` or `B`, so the call is ambiguous.
3. Calling a copy constructor (here, `A(const A&)`) repeatedly is prohibited as [multiple user-defined conversions](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.best.ics-4.5)—rather than allowing one such conversion per level of overload resolution.  So the outermost braces must initialize a `B` from the `A` initialized from `{{a}}` as (permitted) in the second case.  (The middle layer of braces could initialize a `B`, but copying it with the outer layer would be prohibited and there’s nothing else to try to initialize.)
4. Every interpretation involves such a disallowed extra conversion.

No brace elision is involved—we don’t know the outermost target type to allow it.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand it correctly: `f({a})` can be realized by `f(A{a})` or `f(B{a})`. Since the first is a perfect match, it is a better match than the second, and the call is unambiguous. Now we consider the second case. `f({{a}})` can be realized by `f(A{A{a}})`, `f(B{A{a}})`, and `f(B{B{a}})`. The first is prohibited and the second and the third are equally well matches, thus the call is ambiguous. Now consider the third case. `f({{{a}}})` can be realized by `f(A{A{A{a}}})`, `f(B{A{A{a}}})`, `f(B{B{A{a}}})`, and `f(B{B{B{a}}})`. Only the third is not prohibited.

Comment: I think I haven't understood it yet. If the problem was that `f(B{A{a}})` and `f(B{B{a}})` are equally well matches, the call would still be ambiguous when we remove `f(const A&)`. However, the compiler says the opposite.

Comment: @user1494080: The ambiguity is between `f(A{A{a}})` (only the outer of those two is user-defined) and `f(B{A{a}})`.  `f(B{B{a}})` is invalid because the inner conversion is user-defined and so the outer one must not be.  Note the asymmetry: `{a} -> A` is exact-match, but the *resulting* `{B{a}} -> B` is user-defined because overload resolution had to occur to identify the `{a} -> B` conversion.

Comment: Doesn't `f(A{A{a}})` call two times one and the same copy-constructor `A(const A&)`? How can one be user-defined and the other not?

Comment: @user1494080: The inner `{a}` is [specially blessed](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.list-7.1) as being equivalent to using `a` directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "the outermost braces must exact-match-copy a B constructed by the middle set of braces"? The copy constructor of `B` is [not referenced](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f62f6f74dc9b39c0).

Comment: "It would be permissible to initialize a const A& parameter to the constructor for either A or B with that exact match, ...", here the ambiguity [is not because both are exact matches](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef97d685dab9a830), but because the whole conversions are both user-defined conversions.

Comment: @xskxzr: Well, yes: I was saying that both are viable, not that the entire ICS is that exact match.

Comment: @xskxzr: The copy constructor is selected (and blessed) [based on the referenced type](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.ref-2), but the actual initialization of `f`’s parameter knows that it is a reference and merely [binds the reference](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.10).

Comment: I mean when initializing the result object of the prvalue of the referenced type, the copy constructor of `B` is not selected. You can see in [my example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f62f6f74dc9b39c0), I delete the copy constructor but it still works.

Comment: @DavisHerring Sorry, I’m still struggling. `f(B{B{a}})` is prohibited, because the inner conversion is user-defined (I agree), and the outer conversion is also user-defined (that's how I understand you). However, in the third case f(B{B{A{a}}}) is not prohibited, because the inner conversion is an exact match, the middle conversion is user-defined, and the outer one is again a standard conversion? Why is the first `f(B{B{...}})` user-defined and the second `f(B{B{...}})` not?

Comment: @user1494080: Whether the `…` in `f({…})` is `{a}` or `{{a}}`, it’s [not allowed](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.best.ics-4.5) to use a user-defined conversion to `const B&` when attempting to interpret the overall argument as a `B`.  But in either case it *can* convert to `const A&`, including via a user-defined conversion in the three-level case.  …So my analysis of that third case wasn’t quite right; I’ll edit it!

Comment: @xskxzr: I’m not sure that the deleted copy constructor would interfere anyway because of the entity being initialized being a reference, but I got that wrong anyway: only the outermost initialization is of a `B` anyway.  See edit.

Comment: @DavisHerring But even with the edited analysis, we need more than one user-defined conversation in the sequence. `{{a}}` contains one user-defined conversation (the outer one), as explained for case 2. Initializing a `B` from `{{a}}` needs another user-defined conversation. In total, `{{{a}}}` would contain two user-defined conversation. However, if I understood correctly, only one user-defined conversation is allowed in the whole conversation sequence.

Comment: @user1494080: You get one “per level”: you can have a user-defined conversion sequence to form an argument to a [constructor selected to interpret](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list) an enclosing initializer list.