# what are the overload resolution rules of list-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

there are some codes here

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    A(int) {}
};
struct B {
    B(A) {
        std::cout<<"0"<<std::endl;
    }
    B(B const&) {
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }
    B(B&&) {
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    B b0{{0}}; // this is ok  #1
    B b( {0} ); //this is error #2
}
```

g++ report:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17:11: error: call of overloaded ‘B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
  B b({ 0 });
           ^
main.cpp:12:2: note: candidate: B::B(B&&)
  B(B&&) {
  ^
main.cpp:9:2: note: candidate: B::B(const B&)
  B(B const&) {
  ^
main.cpp:6:2: note: candidate: B::B(A)
  B(A) {
```

clang report:

```
main.cpp:17:4: error: call to constructor of 'B' is ambiguous
        B b({ 0 });
          ^ ~~~~~
main.cpp:6:2: note: candidate constructor
        B(A) {
        ^
main.cpp:12:2: note: candidate constructor
        B(B&&) {
        ^
main.cpp:9:2: note: candidate constructor
        B(B const&) {
        ^
1 error generated.
```

{0} will convert to  temporary object A and the contructor B(A) will be selected,
 #1 and #2 are all the  "direct-constructor" form ,why #1 is ok ,#2 has three candidate constructor and is ambiguous?

Comment: `{0}` can also be `B` with implicit converted `A` from `0`.

Comment: @Jarod42  that is question,#1 used B(A) and #2 is ambiguous?

Comment: A a {0}; B b { 0 }; Those are both valid. So, in B b( { 0 }), what does { 0 } stand for? An instance of A or B? Nobody knows, that's why it's ambiguous: are you calling B ( A ) or are you calling B ( const B& ) ? Or even B ( B && ) ?

Comment: And #1 works because B b0{ whatever }; calls the constructor, not the copy or move constructor.

Comment: @MFnx2 thanks ,do you have some quotes of c++ standard about your explantion "B b0{ whatever }; calls the constructor, not the copy or move constructor."?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the number of braces affect uniform initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504463/how-does-the-number-of-braces-affect-uniform-initialization)—note that your direct-initialization is equivalent to one more layer of braces in each case.

Comment: @jackX I would have to dig a bit lol. But, how would you initialize an object if not with the constructor? Isn't that the purpose of the constructor?

Comment: @MFnx  why does not "B b{ whatever}" call copy constructor or move construstor?

Comment: @jackX Why would it? There is no reason to do so, and it doesn't.

Comment: `B b0{whatever};` does call the copy/move constructor in some cases (e.g. if `whatever` is an expression of type `B`, or convertible to `B` and there is no better match)

Comment: @Davis Herring ,maybe they are quite different

Comment: I suggest you add tag c++11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because for #1, the copy and move constructors are disallowed by [[over.best.ics]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.best.ics#4) (emphasized mine):

> However, if the target is
>
> - **the first parameter of a constructor** or
> - the implicit object parameter of a user-defined conversion function
>
> and the constructor or user-defined conversion function is a candidate
>   by
>
> - [over.match.ctor], when the argument is the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization,
> - [over.match.copy], [over.match.conv], or [over.match.ref] (in all cases), or
> - **the second phase of [over.match.list] when the initializer list has exactly one element that is itself an initializer list**, and the target
>     is the first parameter of a constructor of class X, and the conversion
>     is to X or reference to cv X,
>
> user-defined conversion sequences are not considered. [ Note: These
>   rules prevent more than one user-defined conversion from being applied
>   during overload resolution, thereby avoiding infinite recursion.
>    — end note ]

So it is the language rule that distinguishes `({...})` and `{{...}}`. Note the `({...})` case falls into [over.match.ctor] but the argument is NOT the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization, so the first bullet does not apply.

You can further read [Issue 2076](http://Issue%202076) to see it is intended to disallow the copy and move constructors for the inner brace in the `{{...}}` case:

> The resolution of issue 1467 made some plausible constructs
>   ill-formed. For example,
>
> ```
> struct A { A(int); };
> struct B { B(A); };
> B b{{0}};
> ```
>
> This is now ambiguous, because the text disallowing user-defined
>   conversions for B's copy and move constructors was removed from
>   16.3.3.1 [over.best.ics] paragraph 4...

Comment: for B{{anything}}, "{anything}" meet "when the initializer list has exactly one element that is itself an initializer list" this condition and "{anything}" was converted to a temporary object of class A,named tmp,Since the "tmp" meet "when the argument is the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization" this condition,so these "user-defined conversion sequences" are disallowed? For "B({anything})" in this context the temporary object of class A is not  generated by "when the initializer list has exactly one element that is itself an initializer list" rules,so these are allowed?

Comment: @jackX Note "... *or* the second phase of [over.match.list] ...".

Comment: what does the 'the argument is the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization' mean

Comment: @jackX It's related to [\[dcl.init\]/17.6.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.6.3). The wording about "temporary object" is deleted by [P0135](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html). I guess it's a defect of the standard.

Comment: thanks ,the temporary object  is the target object which is tranlated from the expression  by coversion constructor or function? an other question is that 'when the argument is the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization'  ----this condition prevent what situation,can you give a example to help me understand this condition?

Comment: @jackX I'm not sure. Maybe you can ask a new question.

Comment: another question  the answers have not been resolved ,we can [discuse the question is this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208528/ambiguous-with-copy-list-initialization)

Comment: the answer have not interpret why ` B b( {0} );` is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

> Why B b( {0} ); does not work?

```
A a { 0 };
B b { 0 };
```

Those are both valid. So, in `B b( { 0 })`, what does `{ 0 }` stand for? It could be an instance of `A` or `B`. Nobody knows, and that's why it's ambiguous. 
As your compiler states: there are 3 candidates:

```
B::B(A)
B::B(const B&)
B::B(B&&)
```

> Why does B b0 { {0} }; work?

Because you simply call the constructor `B::B(A)`. The copy/move constructors are **not** called here, only the constructor is. A copy constructor would only be invoked if you initialize the instance with an `lvalue` of another instance:

```
B b0 {};
B b1 { b0 }; // copy constructor
```

The same is valid for the move constructor:

```
B b0 {};
B b1 { std::move(b0) }; // move constructor
```

Now, if you pass an instance as a `prvalue`, it will call the constructor, because the instance can be constructed on the fly, that is: the `prvalue` does not need to be copied or moved, it can be **directly** constructed into `b0`. Example:

```
B b0 { {0} };
```

Here, `{0}` can be interpreted as a `prvalue` of type `B`, or of type `A`, but in both cases, **the constructor is called**.

Comment: In my understand , "B b{whatever}" is constructor from whatever ,this form is named direct-list-initialization，make it short,the candidate functions should be all of class B's constructors and use overload resolution to decide which is best match,what I am confused is that "B b(whatever)" and "B b{whatever}" are all direct constructor,why the results of overload resolution are different between them?

Comment: This doesn't really explain anything. If `{0}` could be an instance of A or B in the first case, why couldn't it also be either in the second case?

Comment: @M.M  Totally agree. wthatever "B {anything}" or "B(anything)",they are all direct constructor

Comment: @M.M because in the context of #1, only B::B(A) is a candidate, and therefore {0} is of type A. I'll edit the answer to make that clear.

Comment: @MFnx  why "T t7 { T{} }" did not invoke copy/move constructor ?because the complier optmized for elision constructor rules

Comment: And it compiles because there is only 1 candidate: T::T()

Comment: @MFnx if your interpretation is exactly,why B const& param = A{10} does work? As the same ,why B b( {0} ) does not only use B::B(A)? B b{anything} and B b(anything)  are all direct-initialization except "B b{anything}" firstly match B(std::initialization_list<T>) if it is  exsited

Comment: If you have a constructor with std::initialization_list, it will prefer that before a regular user defined constructor, but this is beyond the scope of this question and has nothing to do with what we are discussing here. Why wouldn't B const& param = A{10} work? It is the same as T t3 = {}; in my example. It just calls the constructor!

Comment: It's just the way it works: Obj myobj = { whatever }; where whatever is a prvalue, calls the constructor! That's how it is, that's how it's always been (C++11).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202728/discussion-between-mfnx-and-jack-x).

Comment: hi,i think the form of T{{anything}} and the form of T({anything}) ,there's no difference between them ,at least,in this example,there are.accroding to standard defination,these forms are named direct initlization,so  what are going to do in the form one should be  done  in the form two,but actually ,the results of overload resolution for them are quite different,and your interpretation does not explain it

Comment: @jackX I removed the lines related to struct T{}. I hope this is clear enough now.