# Templated conversion operator priority

Tags: c++, c++17

Some C++ hacks use the conversion operator the get some information about the constructor.
I would like to know, what is the process when choosing a concrete type for `T` in the resolution of a templated cast operator.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A {
    A(int) { cout << "int" << endl; }
    A() { cout << "def" << endl; }
    A(const A&) { cout << "copy" << endl; }
    A(A&&) { cout << "move" << endl; }
};

struct B {
    template<typename T> operator T()
        { return {}; }
};

template<typename Except>
struct C {
    template<typename T,
             std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T, Except>>* = nullptr> operator T()
        { return {}; }
};

template<typename T>
void f(A a = { T() }) {}

int main() {
    f<B>();
    f<C<A>>();

    return 0;
}
```

This code print this:

```
def
int
```

And not this:

```
int
int
```

Why should I disable conversion for taking the constructor I want (int version)?
The C++ standard says that the return type don't participate in finding a valid template overload, so why it choose this version without complaining about multiple possible resolutions ?

Makefile:

```
EXE = C++Tuple
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++17

run: $(EXE)
    ./$(EXE)
.PHONY: run

$(EXE): main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Plateform:

```sh
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
$ uname -r
4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
```

Comment: Interestingly, GCC & MSVC refuse the compile this (you seem to use Clang).

Comment: It was compiled on WSL with gcc on C++17. `gcc -v` gives `gcc version 7.5.0`. The question is about what is the global priority when finding a valid overload for the cast operator when there is multiple candidates in this specific case, so why A() is called and not A(int) in the first case

Comment: I added Makefile for details, and it yet still seems to compile after verification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, several compilers/versions, including current GCC, do reject this as written.

## Copy initialization

Let's start with a simpler case:

```
template<typename T>
void f(A = T()) {}
```

Here, we have an **expression** of type `T` that we want to (implicitly) convert to `A`.  Unsurprisingly, `B` produces `operator A` as a specialization of its conversion function template, and `C` produces nothing because of SFINAE.

Note that the "expected" return type of a conversion function template definitely **contributes** to template argument deduction (since otherwise it would be impossible to ever deduce anything for them!).  Moreover, `T` is never deduced as `A&&` or so, even though that would be allowed by the constraint; only the singular, "obvious" type is used for such deduction, even though certain other types (*e.g.*, a derived class) are allowed for (non-template) conversion functions (for which no effort needs to expended per *allowed* type).

Clang produces a confusing error message here, saying that it can't convert `C<A>` to `int` in attempting to call the `A(int)` constructor; that conversion is of course possible in general, but is disallowed in this case by the usual rule about **multiple** user-defined conversions in [over.best.ics.general]/4:

> However, if the target is the first parameter of a constructor *[...]* and the constructor or user-defined conversion function is a candidate by *[...]*, [over.match.copy], or *[...]* user-defined conversion sequences are not considered.

## List initialization

However, the multiple-conversions rule doesn't apply to list initialization in general (because you perform normal overload resolution, allowing conversions, [inside each layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54506082/8586227) of braces).  As such, (user-defined) conversions from the argument to the parameter type for each constructor of `A` are considered.

### `B`

Current versions of GCC, ICC, and MSVC all reject this for **ambiguity**, since `B` can be converted to `int` or to `A`.  (ICC helpfully points out that the move constructor is a better match than the copy constructor because of [over.ics.rank]/3.2.3, but there are still two choices.)  It's hard to guess why Clang ignores the former possibility (what with no diagnostic output from it), but the other compilers appear to be **correct**: [dcl.init.list]/3.7 defers to normal overload resolution (except for preferring `std::initializer_list` constructors, which aren't relevant here), and there is no reason to prefer one constructor over the other (since a user-defined conversion sequence followed by an exact-match standard conversion sequence is involved in each case).

### `C<A>`

Again, the deduction for the `const A&` or `A&&` constructors picks `T`=`A` (this time because of [temp.deduct.conv]'s simplifications rather than [over.match.copy]'s restrictions) and finds nothing.  Therefore **only** the "conversion" `C<A>`→`int`→`A` works.  All four compilers agree about this case, although MSVC erroneously issues a warning about an "illegal" double conversion.